# Why does the value of this class variable persist even after resetting it?

Tags: python, class

I have the following code, which is executed multiple times on different binary trees

```
class Solution:
    ans = []

    def getLonelyNodes(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[int]:
        def helper(root):
            if root.left is None and root.right:
                self.ans.append(root.right.val)
                return helper(root.right)
            if root.left and root.right is None:
                self.ans.append(root.left.val)
                return helper(root.left)
            if root.left and root.right:
                return helper(root.left), helper(root.right)
            if root.left is None and root.right is None:
                return

        helper(root)
        ans = self.ans
        self.ans = []
        return ans
```

The problem is that even though I reset `self.ans` at the end, the values in `ans` persist for the next run (i.e. every run adds the previous answer to the current one).

I fixed the issue by moving `self.ans = []` to above the helper function. But I don't understand why it's different to reset the answer at the beginning or end of the function call. How come it doesn't work to reset `self.ans` at the end, but it works at the beginning?

Comment: Placing it before the function call means `self.ans.append` is referring to an instance attribute. Placing it after the function call means `self.ans.append` is referring to `Solution.ans` or the class attribute.

Comment: Try placing `self.ans = []` under `def __init__(self):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.ans` is not the same as `Solution.ans`, even though it may sometimes seem like so.

`self.ans` references an *instance* attribute. Only when it is not found, Python tries to find it in class attributes. Assigning to `self.ans` does not affect `Solution.ans`, instead defines an instance attribute, which will be refferred to whenever you try to get value of `self.ans`.

```
class Foo:
    bar = []
    def reset(self):
        if self.bar is self.__class__.bar:
            print("same object")
        else:
            print("not same")
        self.bar = []
        if self.bar is self.__class__.bar:
            print("same object")
        else:
            print("not same")

foo = Foo()

foo.reset()
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. `self.ans` is different from `Solution.ans`, duh, haha. I guess what tripped me up is that Python decides to use `Solution.ans` when I haven't defined `self.ans` instead of raising an error. +1

Comment: @Alec Is there any particular reason for it being a class variable anyway?

Comment: No, not really, I just put it that way because the solution has an answer, and the class won't be instantiated more than once, but in this case an instance variable makes more sense. I just deleted the class variable and it works, although I suppose to be proper I should declare self.x in an init rather than a function body.

Comment: @Alec or just use plain ol' local variable if it is expected to be empty list anyway

Comment: I had it that way originally but the local variable wouldn't be accessible by the helper function unless I use nonlocal or something. I can't pass it into helper because the algorithm returns at every dead end in the tree, so there would be multiple returned lists